# Minecraft Launcher is not working in Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, java, 18.04, minecraft

I run minecraft.jar through java 8 oracle run time and this is what the launcher gives me:

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is May 2, 2018 12:13:19 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.15.0-20-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_171'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)
...    
Please fix the error and restart.
```

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is also the error that jumps to me ... The issue is that **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** has **Java JDK 11**, **Minecraft** can not run that version of Java ...

The best option would be to install the ***Minecraft Premium Snap Launcher***.

First make sure you have snap support installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

You should log out and back in if this newly installed `snapd`, because it adds a new shell initialization script that includes the necessary locations in your PATH environment variable. Without that, the `snap` command will not be found.

```
sudo snap install minecraft
```

And the other option would be to return to Ubuntu 16.04 (as long as it is supported), which still comes with Java 8.

Comment: When I try sudo snap even after the two first lines given to me by Antonio Duatz it tells me sudo: snap: command not found.

Comment: @TylerPluim Just edited answer: you have to install snap first (use all 3 commands)

Comment: This was the one working solution for me in all my search!

Answer (score 0):

Running **Minecraft 1.14.4+** on **Ubuntu 18+** has issues partially due to the java version and the JVM arguments in the launcher for the Java. You can fix this doing two things (and keep the latest Java).

1. Update your `~/.minecraft/launcher.jar`. For me the version 1.6.68 was not sufficient but **1.6.93** was good enough. You can get it from Mojang [here](https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/eabbff5ff8e21250e33670924a0c5e38f47c840b/launcher.jar), and copy over the old one.

   If you already have launcher that is version 2.x, then read more [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-11993) how to upgrade it.
2. Modify the java parameters in the launcher. Once you start the launcher and log in with your user, before pressing the "Play" button, choose "New Profile", then rename it to something sensible form "Copy of Latest" to "Latest 14+". Then select "**Executable**" and JVM Arguments" check boxes and modify the **JVM Arguments** accordingly:

For Java version 10+ use:

```
-Xmx1G -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

For the older Java 8, should you have it on an older Ubuntu, use:

```
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

This means, remove `-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode` and possibly `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` from the default java arguments.

After this, the launcher was able to successfully start Minecraft 1.14.4 on my Ubuntu machines with Java 10 and Java 8.